# WPF: when move to other page all my ListView data disappear

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have `WPF` application with 2 pages and this `Frame`:

```
<Window>

<Window.DataContext>
        <common:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

  <Grid Name="GridMain" Grid.Row="1">
      <Frame Name="MyFrame"
              NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
              Source="Pages/home.xaml"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

So i have 2 `Pages`

```
Home.xaml
Options.xaml
```

And my `ViewModel`:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<MyData> files;
    public ICommand SliderSpeedValueChangedCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModelBase()
    {
        Files = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
        SliderSpeedValueChangedCommand = new SliderSpeedValueChangedCommand(this);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyData> Files
    {
        get { return files; }
        set
        {
            files = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

So in my `HomePage` i have this `ListView`:

```
<ListView Name="ListViewFiles"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"/>
```

And the user select files that added into this `ListView`.

Now when the user switch to the other `Page` (`Options.xaml`) and then switch back to `HomePage` all the files inside this `ListView` disappear.

Inside this 2 Pages i have also this:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:ViewModelBase/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Page.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelBase x:Key="ViewModelBase"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

What i am doing wrong ?

**Update**

This is how i am switch between `Pages`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ViewModel viewModel;
     private Home home;
     private Options options;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    viewModel = new ViewModel();
    home = new Home();
    options = new Options();
}

    private void ListBoxMenu_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = ListBoxMenu.SelectedIndex;
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                MyFrame.Content = home;
                break;

            case 1:
                MyFrame.Content = options;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

So i have simple command:

```
public class AddFilesCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public ViewModelBase ViewModel { get; set; }

        public AddFilesCommand(ViewModelBase viewModel)
        {            
            ViewModel = viewModel;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return !ViewModel.AddingFiles;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            ViewModel.AddFile();
        }
    }
```

And inside `ViewModelBase` c'tor i am initiate this class:

```
AddFilesCommand = new AddFilesCommand(this);
```

And simple `Button`:

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddFilesCommand}"/>
```

And after click this `Button` the function `Execute` not called.

Comment: It makes no sense to have two ViewModelBase instances in each Page. There should of course only be one, i.e. the one in the DataContext. And how are these view model instances supposed to be connected to the main view model?

Comment: So what i need to change ?

Comment: Besides removing the ViewModelBase instance from Page.Resources? No idea. I don't understand how your application is supposed to work. Maybe both Pages should not set their DataContext at all, and both operate on the single main ViewModel instance.

Comment: Do you know any good tutorial how to implement it ?

Comment: See my update, this 2 pages and globals and inside listbox selection change i am just change my Frame content, i am not using the New keyword but only once in the mainwindows ctor

Comment: See my update now, i add some code regard the main window

Answer (score 0):

When you write the following in your XAML, it creates a new instance of the `ViewModel` class and sets the `DataContext` property to it:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <common:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Since you are creating a `ViewModel` programmatically, you should get rid of this markup. Create a single instance of a view model for each view and only do this one, e.g.:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly Home home;
    private readonly Options options;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
        home = new Home() { DataContext = new ViewModelBase() };
        options = new Options() { DataContext = new ViewModelBase() };
    }

    private void ListBoxMenu_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = ListBoxMenu.SelectedIndex;
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                MyFrame.Content = home;
                break;

            case 1:
                MyFrame.Content = options;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And remove this stuff:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:ViewModelBase/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Page.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelBase x:Key="ViewModelBase"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: Please see my edit, inn order to see that your code works i want to add some files and now my Button command not fired, please see my edit

Comment: BTW, this ViewModel is old and not in use any more so i remove it, ViewModelBase is what i am using so inside mainWindow Ctor what i need to specify ?

Comment: @falukky: You make no sense. You have posted a `ViewModelBase` and there is no `AddFilesCommand` in it. Please post your real code.